# PHP Make a multidimensional array from one mysql Row's columns?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, row

I have the following mysql db row.

```
id | user_id | title_1|desc_1|link_1|title_2|desc_2|link_2|
```

and so on up to 10

from this one row I want to remove id and user id and have the resulting multidimensional array.

the main issue is iterarating over the associative array that is returned by my query and splitting it up into arrays of 3.

```
Array = (

 [0] = array (
    [tite_1] => 'sometitle'
    [desc_1] => 'description'
    [link_1] => 'a link'
 )
  [1] = array (
    [tite_2] => 'sometitle'
    [desc_2] => 'description'
    [link_2] => 'a link'
 )
```

and so on how can I achieve this I am stumped!!?

Comment: this is very poor database design. You should really be looking in to a better design that would accomodate this in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer would be to redesign your database to use 3rd normal form. You should probably drop everything and read up on database normalization before you do anything further.

A proper design would be something like:

```
 CREATE TABLE user_has_links (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   user_id INT,
   title TEXT,
   description TEXT,
   link TEXT
 )
```

To store multiple links per user, you would simply create a new row in this table per link.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to structure your table into two tables like this:

```
parent(id, user_id, more_fields, whatever_you_need_here)

child(parent_id, title, desc, link)
```

Now it'll be very easy to get the data that you want to have.

```
SELECT title, desc, link FROM child WHERE parent_id = 12;
```

Of course, `parent` and `child` should be named appropriately, e.g. `user` and `links`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have a parent_id field in the 1 database?

Comment: Michael, Jon, Middus, Kenaniah you are all correct. I have begun the research already on Normalization this is great advice thank you everyone. Woking off Kenaniah table witch is only one table seems like the correct thing to do, I don't see why I would need a parent table and a child i guess maybe only if i wanted to tell the parent how many rows to expect from the child? what do you guys think?

Comment: In your current design, if you need a third link even for one user, you'd have to ALTER TABLE and add columns.  Then if you need a fourth link you'd have to ALTER TABLE again.  If you store links in a child table, its easier because you just add as many rows as you want for each user.

Comment: @Stoosh Because I didn't know more about his application. It could be a user table with username, email etc. or something entirely different.

Comment: @BillKarwin Great explanation! Thanks for chiming in for me :).

Answer (score 2):

The real solution here is to fix your database to normalize these columns into other tables.  However, if you are not in a position to fix your database, this code will do the job:

```
// $output will hold your full result set
$output = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  // For each row returned, add a new array to $output
  $output[] = array(
    // The new array consists of 10 sub-arrays with the correct
    // keys and values
    array (
      "title"=>$row['title1'],
      "desc"=>$row['desc1'],
      "link"=>$row['link1']
    ),
    array (
      "title"=>$row['title2'],
      "desc"=>$row['desc2'],
      "link"=>$row['link2']
    ),
    ...,
    ...,
    array (
      "title"=>$row['title10'],
      "desc"=>$row['desc10'],
      "link"=>$row['link10']
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: This is a "red tape fix", though. As you can see, it's very easy to mess things up. One typo and *boom* ;). So as Michael, Jon and the others said: normalize your database if possible.

Comment: Sorry, something went wrong with the concurrent editing. I just fixed the `/title1/title2` and did not mean to remove your comments.

Comment: @middus I fixed it, that's ok